# What is a verb for "to be identical"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, intransitive-verbs

What is a verb for the meaning "To be identical"?

> **identical** *adjective* 
>  Things that are identical are exactly the same. 
>  *[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/identical)*

For instance, instead of saying "Diamonds are never identical", I can say:

> Diamonds never [insert a verb here].

Comment: The crystalline structure of a natural diamond is like a snowflake, no two diamonds are alike. Good luck!

Answer (score 14):

The verb *match* can be used intransitively for the meaning 'to be identical'. The definition of the intransitive verb *match* for this sense from *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/114883?rskey=ACodhN&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid)* is:

> (of two or more things) to possess identical or complementary characteristics; to go or fit together (also with *up*).

*[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/match#:%7E:text=(intransitive)%20To%20agree;%20to%20be%20equal;%20to%20correspond.)* provides a more succinct definition and a very relevant example:

> **match** 
> (*intransitive*) To agree; to be equal; to correspond. 
> *These two copies are supposed to be identical, but they don't match.*

Although, it is not that usual or natural to say:

> Diamonds never match.

A natural way to say is:

> (Two) Diamonds are never alike.

Still, one can find usages with the structure 'Xs never match'. Here are two examples I've found:

> My brother Otto had a sweater with the very same snowflakes. Absurd, our father said, —**snowflakes never match**. Each one has its own crystal network. 
> <sub>*[The Rags of Time: A Novel](https://books.google.es/books?id=pwsF6n2rU-QC&pg=PT67&lpg=PT67&dq=%22snowflakes%20never%20match%22&source=bl&ots=xpCzsMxHYi&sig=ACfU3U12wR-sw9EuS4gZX9uTj-oFtA8IRQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG8crAoI35AhWqQPEDHWzwDb8Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22snowflakes%20never%20match%22&f=false)* by Maureen Howard</sub>

> The DNA might be identical, but the **fingerprints never match**. In more than a century of use, in every country on earth, no two people have ever been shown to share the same fingerprint. 
> <sub>*[A Question of Evidence: The Casebook of Great Forensic Controversies, from Napoleon to O. J.](https://books.google.es/books?id=Y0cx_2zPddoC&pg=PA97&dq=%22fingerprints%20never%20match%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1ksqZpY35AhUzXvEDHfjUCucQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22fingerprints%20never%20match%22&f=false)* by Colin Evans</sub>

---

Additionally, the verb *conform* can be used intransitively for this meaning as well; but it doesn't work for your example sentence in colloquial usage. Perhaps, it can be used in a technical context in mathematics, geometry etc. *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conform)* definition of the intransitive *conform*, of the first sense:

> to be similar or identical 
> *also* : to be in agreement or harmony —used with *to* or *with*

Comment: Often used as 'matching'

Comment: A note on snowflakes: that is a fallacy based on an insufficient sample. In a given handful of snow in which individual flakes can be seen, it is vanishingly unlikely to see two the same, but out of the billions or trillions of snowflakes that have ever fallen, there is absolutely no evidence to back up the assertion that no two of those had exactly the same crystalline structure.

Answer (score 5):

The *be* in *be identical* is a verb, or at least acts like one enough to be inflected and used as a verb. The technical term is *predicate adjective*; the *be* does the predicate part, and the *identical* does the adjective part.

There are also predicate nouns, like *be a dentist*. All of these can be treated as single, normally intransitive, verbs of more than one word, like *sit down*. Since verbs are the prototypical predicate, we don't hafta call them "predicate verbs", but they're in the same category.

Since English can make predicates out of just about anything, there is no reason to have a different special verb that means the same as a particular adjective, unless there's something special about it.

However, there are several ways to say things, especially negative things, so the actual question provides an example of what's wanted, which can be managed nicely.

- *Diamonds are never identical.*

The question asks us to insert a verb after *never*:

- *Diamonds never [are identical].*

Comment: Copula verbs ostensibly capture the idea of equality. IN English though the semantics is one way (ie set membership A bear is a mammal but not  How about some variation on 'equals'? 'Diamonds never equate (... to each other)'.?

Comment: "Copular verbs" in English are not a natural set; there's _be_ and then there's a bunch of raising and other odd verbs, well on their trajectories to becoming auxiliaries, though not there yet. But they don't "capture" any ideas of equality.

Comment: Shouldn't one mention  a state or condition [be + adjective] versus **doing something** Aren't predicates in a different universe than verbs that do things?

Comment: There are active predicates and there are stative predicates. Both can appear as adjectives or as verbs. _Rent_ is active, but _own_ is stative, for instance. _Honest_ is active, but _tall_ is stative. There are several different types of both categories, and quite a few words (naturally; this is English) can fall into several classes, depending on context.

Comment: Be honest, be tall, as opposed to rent a house, own a house. Isn't there as basic dichotomy there? Or not?

Comment: *_He's owning the house_ but _He's renting the house_; stative predicates can't use the progressive -- they're already states. Similarly, _He's being honest_ but *_He's being tall_. And other tests, like imperatives: _Be honest!/*Be tall!_.

Answer (score 4):

No there isn't. Structures like "To be X" don't generally have corresponding verbs. There are not (for example) verbs corresponding to "To be green", "To be tall", to be moving", "to be intelligent". English uses the verb "to be" and an appropriate adjective.

Comment: "To be similar"="to resemble" so I don't see why *a priori* there couldn't be a verb "to be identical".

Comment: I didn't say they **never** existed, I said they **generally** don't. And in this case there isn't. If you have a better answer feel free to write it.

Comment: Right, they generally don't. be + x [adjective] describes a state, not an action.

Comment: In this case, I'd say there is such a verb - namely, "match". For your other examples, "tower" might work for "to be tall", and "locomote" could perhaps be a fit for "to be moving".

Comment: @Showsni, *match* does not mean *to be identical*. For example in the Uno card game we say that a red 5 matches a green 5 card, but they are not identical. We also say that a key matches a lock if it is the correct key, out of a number of keys, to fit the lock.

Comment: @Peter It can be used to mean certain elements match - for example, when the numbers in Uno match - but a perfect match is one where something matches in every respect, for example you'd say fingerprints are a match to another set if they are completely identical.

Comment: @Showsni If you cut a picture into two parts you can see (by putting the parts alongside each other) that the two parts are a perfect match. They are not identical though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at an informal way then you can use "twin".

> Diamonds never twin!

In the new age lingo, twinning is the word used when two people wear a matching outfit.

Answer (score -2):

There is "coincide"

> **coincide**  INTRANSITIVE VERB
> 1.1 Correspond in nature; tally.
> *‘the interests of employers and employees do not always coincide’*
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/coincide)

[HERE](https://www.lexico.com/synonyms/coincide) we find a list of synonyms for this sense:
tally, correspond, agree, accord, concur, match, fit, be in agreement, be consistent, conform, equate, harmonize, be in tune, be compatible, dovetail, correlate, be the same as, parallel
*informal* square
*North American informal* jibe
*archaic* quadrate

Perhaps one of these will be what the OP searches?
*‘Diamonds never match.’*
*‘Diamonds never concur.’*
*‘Diamonds never jibe.’*

Answer (score -4):

What about replicate?

> Diamonds never **replicate**

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/replicate) defines it *Make an exact copy of; reproduce.*

Comment: What about some references that explain why this is the right word.

Comment: _Replicate_ is not used intransitively so "Diamonds never replicate" doesn't work. The transitive verb _replicate_ can be used like this: "You can never replicate a diamond." I believe the only time _replicate_ can be intransitive is in the context of biology, for the meaning 'to reproduce'.

Comment: *Duplicate* is the same; I thought it could be intransitive but Lexico doesn't have an intransitive sense and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duplicate) says it means "to become duplicated" not "to be duplicated" ("repeat" might be better although it has different connotations - e.g. a pattern repeats).

Comment: Wrong word. "Replicate" suggests that the diamond does the work of making an exact copy of itself.